# create threading and assign function to it using c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to create threads and assign  different function for each thread using c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely using the new Task class in .net 4 is the easiest way.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => mymethod());
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have good reasons for creating threads, you should prefer using [the managed thread pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx) instead and if .NET 4 is an option, you should take a look at the new [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) class.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Thread T = new Thread(SomeFunction);
 T.Start();
```

Comment: if functions has many arguments like this function :
sent_to_server(string init_message, List<string> all_action_messages, byte[] buffer, ASCIIEncoding encoder, NetworkStream clientStream)

Answer (score 0):

```
var delegates = new []{NamedMethod1, NamedMethod2, ()=>DoSomething()}

var threads = new List<Thread>();

foreach(var theDelegate in delegates) threads.Add(new Thread(theDelegate));

foreach(var thread in threads) thread.Start();

foreach(var thread in threads) thread.Join();
```